# How to get the end of a C++ string stream?

Tags: c++, string, stream

I'm adding functions to my (simple) [log class](http://code.google.com/p/game-core/source/browse/trunk/GCore/GC_Log.h) to make it usable like a stream.
Currently, after some modifications, I got this (in my cpp):

```
// blah blah blah...
// note: here String is a defined as: typedef std::string String;

void Log::logMessage( const String& message )
    {
        logText(); // to be sure we flush the current text if any (when "composing" a message)
        addText( message ); 
        logText(); // really log the message and make the current text empty
    }

// blah blah blah...

    Log& operator<<( Log& log, const std::stringstream& message )
    {
        log.logMessage( message.str() );
        return log;
    }

    Log& operator<<( Log& log, const String& message )
    {
        log.addText( message );
        return log;
    }
```

Now in my "client" app I'm using this code to check the result (m_log is a valid pointer as you have already guessed):

```
gcore::Log& log = *m_log;
log << getName() << " : application created.";
log << "This is a test for " << getName();
```

Now the problem I got is that logText() (and logMessage) is never called because this test code will only call the << operator with String.
What I need is a way to call logText() when the given steam of string is finished :

```
log << getName() << " : application created.";
```

would be equivalent to

```
log.addText( getName() );
log.addText( " : application create." );
log.logText();
```

I'm not sure how to do this or even if it's possible. My first guess is that it would be possible to use std::endl at the end of the stream like this :

```
log << getName() << " : application created." << std::endl;
```

Or something equivalent, but if it's possible to do it without adding objects to the stream, that would be nice.

Any idea?

Comment: Why the delay until logText() is called, to really log the message?

Comment: Yes, addText() will fill a std::stringstream while logText() will do some work to "log" the string result of the stream. logText() write the string value in a file and standard streams and add some time informations, so the "log" is have to be considered done only once logText() is called. If the text was empty, the call is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temp object and use his destructor to catch the end of the statement:

following code should give you the basic idea

```
class Log
{
public:
  class Sublog
  {
  public:
    Sublog(const std::string& message)
    {
      std::cout << message;
    }

    void addText(const std::string& message)
    {
      std::cout << message;
    }

    ~Sublog()
    {
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    Sublog& operator<<(const std::string& message )
    {
      this->addText(message);
      return *this;
    }
  };

};

Log::Sublog operator<<( Log& log, const std::string& message )
{
  return Log::Sublog(message);
}
```

which would be used like this

```
int main()
{
    Log log;
    log << "Foo" << "bar";
    log << "baz" << "plop";
}
```

after each semicolon, the destructor of Sublog is called

---

Klaim: the (working and effective) implementation of this solution in my case :

in the Log header :

```
    /** To allow streaming semantic on logs (used in << operator) .
*/
class LogStreamer
{
public:

    LogStreamer( Log& log, const String& text )
        : m_log( log )
    {
        m_log.addText( text );
    }

    ~LogStreamer()
    {
        m_log.logText();
    }

    LogStreamer& operator<<( const String& text )
    {
        m_log.addText( text );
        return *this;
    }

private:

    Log& m_log;

};

GCORE_API LogStreamer operator<<( Log& log, const String& message );
```

and in the cpp file:

```
LogStreamer operator<<( Log& log, const String& message )
{
    return LogStreamer( log, message );
}
```

Comment: Wow, using a temporary object and its destructor, did not think of that. +1

Comment: Thanks, it woked really nice, with only one tiny temporary object!
I'll edit the post to gives the current full solution as some details had to be fixed.